# Query data from DynamoDB using Powershell and .NET

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to build a project that will compare data of an excel file with the data from dynamoDB. I wish to use Powershell and .Net with this, but suggestions are always welcome. So far I found this article that shows a straightforward solution (https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/dynamodb-ado-powershell.rst), but when I tried it, it showed a pop up saying that I have to avail the trial to continue.

[image]

I read a lot of articles already, but they don't really explain much. The most recent forum I read was this (https://github.com/aws/aws-tools-for-powershell/issues/41) and it's basically saying that there's no other way to do this other than what I'm doing right now; It also doesn't offer that much control with the data. So I guess my question is: What is the best way to query and manipulate dynamoDB data using powershell only?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark since I don't use AWS but it appears Amazon is going through different licensing models with different bits.  This looks like a good place to start to ensure you have the correct library and any required licensing to use the Amazon PowerShell cmdlets:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/aws-tools-for-powershell-is-now-generally-available-with-version-4-0/.

Comment: Looks to me like you are using some dodgy cdata version. Download Amazon's tools https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AWS.Tools.Common/4.0.5.0

Comment: @Tommy I tried that and it still offered the trial. Thank you though.